# Concatenating 0s in excel

Tags: excel

I have these data:

[image]

Data format:

```
V1  V2  V3      RESULT  EXPECTED RESULT
0   0           000     00
0   0   1       00      00
0   0   0       000     000
0               000     0
0   1           00      0
0   1           00      0
```

In the Result cells, I have the following formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN("",FALSE,IF(A2:C2=0,A2:C2,""))
```

I tried to write the same formula with concatenate and text function too but couldn't get the result I wanted. How can I get the expected results? Can I get some help, please? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option using `REPT` together with `COUNTIF`:

```
=REPT(0,COUNTIF(A2:C2,0))
```

[image]